# Word for something near in time

Tags: word-request

What is the appropriate term for indicating something being close in terms of time? It's 27 March today, and suppose the exams are going to begin from 1st April. How to express it?

Exams are close by.

Exams are nearby.

Or something else?

Comment: Surely, with *exams* the most appropriate word is *nigh*.

Comment: Exams are soon.

Comment: Adding a note of dread, "Exams loom!"

Answer (score 2):

There are quite a few options to choose from:

1. Exams are starting soon.
2. Exams are starting shortly. (For rather short periods like an hour for example)
3. The exams will start before long.
4. Exams are starting in the short run.
5. Exams are starting one of these days.
6. The exams will start before you know it. (You won't have to wait long)
7. Exams are coming up.
8. Exams are close. (Are not too much far away in time)

If the time is a few day or next week you could say:

1. The exams are starting in a few (couple of) days.
2. The exams are starting next week.

Oh, and since you mentioned the 1st if April:

1. The start of the next month is exam time!
2. Exams are going to start in the beginning of April (the next month).

Answer (score 1):

The common word here is "soon". "Exams are soon" or "Exams are coming soon."

You can also say "the time is near" or "the time is close" or variations. Like, "Exam time is near" or "The time for our exams is close".

Answer (score 1):

*Soon* is the common choice in English to indicate an event that is about to take place. For added emphasis or to add a faint wisp of foreboding, you might try:

> Exams are *imminent*.